# How can flashing cursor when doing edit in a GridColumn in a Xtra Grid Control

Tags: c#, grid, edit, xtragrid, datagridviewcolumn

I am using a Xtra Grid Control (Dev express 11.2). All columns are Read Only

> AllowEdit = false

and I have created a function witch user can make `Right-Click`and choose `edit` in a `column`, then this column if is '`amaColumn`' or '`phoneColumn`' then change to `AllowEdit=true;` 
My Code is bellow

```
private void SetFocusedColumnOptionAllowEdit(bool allowEdit) 
{
     try 
     {                
        GridColumnCollection column = mainGridView.Columns;
        GridColumn focusedColumn = column.View.FocusedColumn;
        switch (focusedColumn.Name) 
        {

            case "amaColumn":
            case "phoneColumn":
                 focusedColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = allowEdit;
                 break;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
        _logger.ErrorException("SetFocusedColumnOptionAllowEdit", ex);
     }  
}
```

But then to that I want to pu the cursor to flashing in the end of text without extra click in these columns. Is it possible?

if yes how can to that in c#?

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to open editor first. Then you will be able to put a cursor at an appropriate position:

```
mainGridView.ShowEditor();
TextEdit editor = (TextEdit)mainGridView.ActiveEditor();
editor.SelectionStart = editor.Text.Length - 1;
editor.SelectionLength = 0;
```